# ASP.NET - Request Params and the "&amp;" Separator Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

We have some UTF-8 XML being returned by a REST handler that contains urls. These urls have an ampersand (&), which when escaped to be UTF-8 compliant, look like this:

```
http://domain.com?param1=a&amp;param2=b
```

The problem is, when this is then cut/pasted into a browser, the result does not correctly separate based on the escaped ampersand. Below is an example:

This works:

```
http://api.citysourced.com/reportimage.ashx?reportid=30885&imagesize=Small
```

These do not:

```
http://api.citysourced.com/reportimage.ashx?reportid=30885&amp;imagesize=Small
http://api.citysourced.com/reportimage.ashx?reportid=30885%26imagesize=Small
```

Is there an issue with my IIS configuration (IIS 6)? The handler above is a standard generic handler written in C# .NET 4.0.

I've looked at the other articles here, and none of them have the right answer.

Thanks.

Comment: If you load the XML with an actual XML parser (as opposed to a program such as Notepad, or something involving regex mishandling), you get `http://domain.com?param1=a&param2=b`, which is the URL that works. There's no reason that I can tell that those URLs that don't work should work. Could you explain why you think they should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your IIS configuration. XML has certain [predefined entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) (characters) that it must escape, otherwise they would break the document. You just need to unescape the data when you consume it.